# Bool Variable and string value compare in C#

Tags: c#, string, compare

If I declared a `bool isTrue = false; // init it to false`

and I can get the value from a `string strVal = T; // I assumed it is the TRUE value`

I heard it is not a good code style to compare string in C# like

`if (isTrue.tostring() == strVal) {}.`

Some time, I covert the the string variable to enum then I can compare it more convenient.

Is there any good method to do it?

Comment: still typo?
no need to do "strVal.tostring()"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you parse the string into a boolean first.

Try this:

```
bool someBool = false; 

string boolVal = "true";
bool stringBool;
bool.TryParse(boolVal, out stringBool);

if (someBool == boolVal) 
{

}
```

Alternatively to handle 'T' and 'F' try these methods:

```
public bool ParseString(string maybeBool)
{
    return ParseString(maybeBool, false);
}

public bool ParseString(string maybeBool, bool def)
{
    bool stringBool;
    if (bool.TryParse(maybeBool, out stringBool))
        return stringBool;

    if (string.Equals(maybeBool, "T", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (string.Equals(maybeBool, "F", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return false;

    return def;
}
```

Comment: @Graphain. I debugged and found it doesn't work when the `boolVal = "T"` not `"true"`; Then I can get `stringBool = false` after `TryParse()` How can I cover the problem with your method? Thanks.

Comment: No TryParse doesn't handle "T" it will return false (i.e failed to parse) in this case. Check its return value and if TryParse returns false do some custom parsing to handle "T", "F" etc... You should maybe throw an exception if boolVal still doesn't match anything.

Comment: The new example will not compile because 'default' is a keyword.

Comment: @mjf196 okay so rename the variable and I'll do the same on the example, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `bool.Parse()` method instead.

Comment: or bool.TryParse is even better if you aren't sure that the input string is a valid bool value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert boolean values to strings in order to compare the two. You can simply compare the two boolean values directly:

```
if (isTrue == boolVal) {}
```

**Update:** (following updated question)

You can parse a string into a boolean and use the resulting boolean in your comparison (as above), using either `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse`.

Comment: Sorry for my original post above. Acturally the `boolVal` is a ` strVal` - `T`. I take is as a `bool` value `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool.Parse(boolVal) == isTrue
```

Answer (score 1):

you may compare boolean type instead.

```
bool temp = bool.Parse(strVal);

if(isTrue == temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version which i use a lot is simply `Convert.ToBoolean(stringFromBoolVal)`

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do string comparisons:

```
if (string.Equals(isTrue.ToString(), strValue)) { }
```

Comment: add .ToLower() on both sides then! ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this simple way to determine the value of bool variable `isTrue`:

```
isTrue = strVal == "T";
```

`isTrue` will return true if the strVal is equaled to "T". And return false if not.